# Reboot application without restarting Mac

Tags: crash, preview, restart, force-quit

Whenever I try to open Preview on my MacBook, the application doesn't work and I need to force quit it. I would usually restart my Mac to resolve the issue, but I have some code running on the same Mac, which will be done in several days only. Is there anything I can do now?

What caused Preview to freeze was trying to open several EPS files simultaneously, and whenever I try to open Preview now, I see all those EPS files as currently open (their names are shown if I hover over the Preview icon).

Comment: Presumably simply relaunching it does the same again...?

Comment: I've tried relaunching several times and it doesn't help!

Comment: Try `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState`, follow the alias & delete the folder contents. Relaunch.

Comment: @Tetsujin the last thing I used Preview for was trying to open several EPS files simultaneously, which caused it to freeze. Whenever I launch Preview now, all these EPS files are in the files listed as open (I see their names if I hover over the Preview icon)

Comment: You ought to have included any relevant info in your original question - we cannot see over your shoulder or know what you did.

Comment: Thanks, @Tetsujin, I try to delete those folder contents now

Comment: Apple found a security hole in .eps files, so quietly modified everything related to that: on Sierra, .eps files are instantly converted to .pdf and opened as such, and in iOS (starting with 10.0 IIRC) .eps files received as mail attachments are not any more rendered. I checked to open three .eps files simultaneously and work ok, Preview is not freezing.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks a lot, your approach solved the issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After having opened something that crashes an app, subsequent launches will automatically try to reopen the file that crashed it... & round you go in circles.

The usual 'first-fix' for this type of issue is to clear the 'history' of what it was trying to open.

Many apps store data in this way, that's how they can set everything back up exactly as you left it, after a reboot, etc.

They live in `/Library/Saved Application State/`
specifically for Preview, at `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState` the file in here is an Alias - usually they're not so you can usually just delete the specific app's folder & it will recreate it as necessary - but for an Alias it's safer to follow it by right clicking & 'Show Original' which saves the Alias being accidentally broken.

Delete the contents of the original folder but not the folder itself & your App should launch cleanly.